# Is vue@2.6.12 needed for the 4.5.12 vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nodes

When I run the command `npm list -g vue`, I obtain the following output:

[image]

Is vue@2.6.12 needed for the 4.5.12 @vue/cli? Since I have made a re-install, I am wondering if this is a remnant from my old installation or if it was added with the 4.5.12 @vue/cli install.

If it is a remnant, how can I uninstall it? I am only finding online how to remove vue-cli, but not the vue component itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a remnant. `@vue/cli` depends on `vue@2.6.12` to scaffold Vue 2.x projects. If you need to use Vue CLI, you can't uninstall `vue@2.6.12`.